# How to append string using '||" in sql?

Tags: sql, plsql

I have tried the query from table detail. I want to select names like 'gani' and 'gani-1'(xxxx and xxxx-1)

```
select a.name,a.age from detail a,detail b where a.name=b.name || '-1' order by a.name;
```

which is working and returning a name  "gani-1" but,

```
  select a.name,a.age from detail a,detail b where a.name|| '-1' =b.name order by a.name;
```

or

```
select a.name,a.age from detail a,detail b where b.name= a.name|| '-1' order by a.name;
```

are not working (they are loading continuously for long time)

I want both the names like "gani" and "gani-1" to be selected.

Thanks in advance...

I tried condition

```
 select a.name,a.age from detail a,detail b where (a.name || '-1' = b.name or a.name = b.name||'-1')
```

which is returning required result with both names.

But when i add some condition like they shoul be of particular age

```
 (a.name || '-1' = b.name or a.name = b.name||'-1') and (a.age=25 and b.age=25)
```

doesnot work...

Comment: I'm still confused why you are joining a table to itself using a where clause? What is it that you are trying to do here?

Comment: I don't know why you are using the same table twice, but here's a quick example: select a.name, a.age from detail a where a.name = 'gani' or a.name = 'gani' || '-1'

Comment: This was because i dont know gani and gani-1

Comment: I want to select names of the particular format xxxx and xxxx-1 and also both are present in the table

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: please undelete (restore) your answer. Yours is the best one so far.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
select a.name, a.age
from detail a, detail b
where a.name = b.name and
      a.name like (a.name || '-1')
order by a.name;
```

Comment: Caution :This is not a Best/Optimal Soultion

Comment: `a.name like (a.name || '-1')` has no wildcard characters, and is thus exactly equivalent to `a.name = (a.name || '-1')` which will obviously be FALSE for all values of `a.name`. Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
select a.name, a.age from detail a, detail b where substr(a.name,len(a.name)-2) = b.name
```